# How do I say "Brief Mass of the Butterfly" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

I am writing a [mass setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_(music)) that I would like to call the "Mass of the Butterfly". Since it doesn't include all of the ordinary, it's a [*missa brevis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missa_brevis).

I started with Google Translate, but it is convinced I mean "mass" in the physics sense and gives me constructions based around *massa*. The word I think I want is *papilio*, and I think it should be in the genitive, so *papilionis*.

How do I combine all of this? Is the complete phrase *"Missa Brevis Papilionis"* correct (and is it idiomatic to capitalize it)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked up historical *missae,* and the custom seems to be to either name the piece short (*missa brevis*), or give the name in full without the length (*missa <hoc nomen>*). Though Haydn provides an example with *de*: *Missa brevis Sancti Joannis de Deo*. In your case I'd go with *missa brevis papilionis.*

With regard to capitalisation I'd follow modern rules if you want a familiar feel, or none if you want to comply with Ancient Latin.

Comment: I'm not quite I understand your first paragraph. Do you think you could clarify it a bit, perhaps with some examples? Thanks!

Comment: I was thinking of *missa brevis* versus *missa <hic nomen>.* Though on further looking I found adding a name to the *brevis* was in fact not unheard of. Haydn for instance called his short mass *Missa brevis Sancti Joannis de Deo,* so there is a pattern to follow. I've amended the original answer.

Comment: I edited your post to include this information.